# Vertically center img inside bootstrap col/row

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I know that this topic is covered endlessly already but I've tried many solutions and none have worked. In the snippet below, how can I make the image vertically centered within the col/row divs? Solutions using jQuery are preferred (I'm more likely to break CSS). I don't know the height of the image in advance.

```css
.row {
  /* Just for demo */
  border: 2px solid black;
}

/* My latest attempt at centering - this code can all be removed if desired*/
.book-image-container {
  display: table;
  table-layout: fixed;
}
.book-image {
  display: table-cell;
  vertical-align: middle;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js">
</script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-2">
      <div class="book-image-container">
        <img class="book-image" src="http://static.loot.co.za/images/x80/691858851600179215$622D8483">
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-6">
      <h3>Lorem ipsum</h3>
      <p>Bla bla bla</p>
      <p>Bla bla bla</p>
      <p>Bla bla bla</p>
      <p>Bla bla bla</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Edit:

Got it working thanks to Jurik, here's the minimal CSS required:

```css
.row {
  /* Just for demo */
  border: 2px solid black;
}

.book-image-container {
  display: table-cell;
  vertical-align: middle;
  height: 116px;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js">
</script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-2">
      <div class="book-image-container">
        <img class="book-image" src="http://static.loot.co.za/images/x80/691858851600179215$622D8483">
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-6">
      <h3>Lorem ipsum</h3>
      <p>Bla bla bla</p>
      <p>Bla bla bla</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to give your class `book-image-container` the `display: table-cell` css attribute and a height.

```
.book-image-container {
  display: table;
  table-layout: fixed;
  display: table-cell;
  vertical-align: middle;
  height: 116px;
}
```

Comment: Thanks! Looks like this contained some redundant stuff and the `.book-image` CSS was no longer needed. Edited my question with the minimal CSS.

Answer (score 0):

I wouldn't solve this with jQuery, but hey, you asked for it: http://jsbin.com/dumifahuja/edit?html,css,js,console,output

Find the closest parent row's height, subtract the image's height from it, then divide that by two and set the `margin-top` to that amount.

Comment: Thanks for your help! Currently I'm going to go with Jurik's answer (or rather my version of it) because it's quite simple, but if I was to go with this I don't think it would work because the images may be different sizes.

Comment: No worries, this is a problem better solved by CSS ;-)